# Can Javascript detect if DIV height or default font size changes?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

**Question:** Can Javascript detect if the height of a DIV changes?  If not can it detect if the user changes the default font size in the browser?

I've looked through the [Mozilla Event Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) but I can't find an event that would work for my problem.

**Background:** My site is built with fonts using REM font sizes.

For example,

```
h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}
```

My header uses a `.jpg` `background-image` with a height of 320px.  Unfortunately if the user increases their font size by more than double the header grows taller than 320px and the background image looks terrible.  Under those circumstances I'd like to use Javascript to switch the background image to a color which will look fine.

`resize` detects if the width changes so that won't help.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', myFunction);
```

`scroll` detects if the scroll bar is used.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction);
```

I can't find an event to solve this one.

Comment: There is a library which does the same thing. 
http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

Comment: If the CSS is set at `style` attribute of element, yes, the changes can be observed.